# What does it mean when an awk script has code outside curly braces?

Tags: awk

Going through an awk tutorial, I came across this line

```
substr($0,20,5) == "HELLO" {print}
```

which prints a line if there is a "HELLO" string starting at 20th char.

Now I thought curly braces were necessary at the start of an awk script and an 'if' for this to work, but it works without nevertheless.

Can some explain how it evaluates?

Comment: As the answer pointed out `{print}` part is redundant here

Comment: Stop guessing at the syntax and just read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have:

```
{ action }
```

...then that action runs on every line. By contrast, if you have:

```
condition { action }
```

...then that action runs only against lines for which the condition is true.

---

Finally, if you have *only* a condition, then the default action is `print`:

```
NR % 2 == 0
```

...will thus print every other line.

---

You can similarly have multiple pairs in a single script:

```
condition1 { action1 }
condition2 { action2 }
{ unconditional_action }
```

...and can also have `BEGIN` and `END` blocks, which run at the start and end of execution.